# Fatal Error - Developer Console Event Object

Tags: field-update, event

I'm trying to run some tests using the developer console on the Event object.

```
  `List<Event> even = new List<Event>([SELECT Id, Status_Event__c, Activity_Cost__c    
                                       FROM Event 
                                       WHERE Status_Event__c='Completed']);

 for(Event e: even){
 e.Activity_Cost__c =30.00;
 }update even;
```

`

I get this error:

**13:26:27:397 FATAL_ERROR System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id someID; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, You can not **update fields except ReminderDateTime and IsReminderSet on a child event.: [Activity_Cost__c]**

It is not possible to update an Event custom field from the developer console or from any where else?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the events that your query retrieved are due to shared events.These events are child event and has originated when someone has invited you for event and during this salesforce creates multiple event for each assignee.

Filter the rows to get only parent Events.Use Ischild field and query Ischild=false

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_event.htm

You can use database.update with false parameter that will allow success for all events except shared events.